# Using a slider controller to update map data/shading? Example included

Tags: javascript, interactive

How can I create a similar map without using Flash?
[map example here](http://visual.ly/salubrious-nation?view=true)

I have a map of the U.S. with each state colored based on annual data (heat map). For instance, obesity rates from 2000 to 2010 (each year would have different values for each state). I would like the user to scrub with the slider to update the map for each year similar to the example above.

I'm very new to Javascript so I'm wondering if there's a library that could help. I'm aware of raphael.js but haven't seen any examples of this particular behavior. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the OpenLayers API to create similar heat map without using Flash. OpenLayers API is based on javascript and pretty simple to use. First, you need to look into the basics:

http://openlayers.org/

OpenLayers HeatMap Examples:

http://maps.seai.ie/wind/

http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/heatMap.html

http://sloweb.org.uk/ollie/heatmap/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although the last example uses a slider, I'm trying to achieve something with less detail so it redraws faster as the slider scrubs back and forth. Cycling through different versions of a map with a slider is my main goal. Again, thanks for reply